# Is a dedicated Oracle database required for Artifactory?

Tags: oracle, artifactory

In JFrog's [Artifactory Installation Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+Artifactory),  there are 2 conflicting statements under the Configuring the Database, Oracle   section:

1. In the Overview:
   For Artifactory to run with Oracle you ***must create a dedicated Oracle database instance*** and then configure Artifactory to use it as described in the following sections.
2. Under Creating the Artifactory Oracle Database, Item #2
   Recommendation: With both of the above options (Full DB and DB-Filesystem), it is ***recommended to create a dedicated table space*** and use AL32UTF8 encoding.

I bring up this issue, because we were looking to just create a new tablespace in a pre-exisiting repository type database.

Also on the site, under SQLServer is this tidbit, written by a different person:
Optimizing Artifactory when running with MS SQL Server
When running Artifactory with Microsoft SQL Server ***you may create the Artifactory schema on an existing server*** used for other applications, however for optimal performance, we recommend creating a dedicated Microsoft SQL Server database instance and then configure Artifactory to use it as described in the following sections.

So I guess my question is this.  For Oracle, is it a recommendation or a requirement to have a dedicated database instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently upgraded artifactory from version 4.9.0 to 6.1.0  along with DB migration from derby to postgreSQL. Although it is written to have a dedicated host for the postgreSQL server I have tested both the above activities on the same host and it worked fine. For the actual upgrade we have a dedicated DB instance.

But I guess by dedicated host the artifactory might be referring to best pratice.